# dictionary-comprehension with conditional calling nested list-comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary of keys and lists. I'd like to iterate through the dictionary, get each list, iterate through each list and apply a condition, then append that filtered list to a new dictionary.

The function already works imperatively. Can I do the same functionally with list and dict comprehensions? The main blocker is that the wrapping dict-comp has a conditional which needs length of the list-comp.

Here it is working imperatively:

```
filtered_prediction_dict = {}
for prediction, confidence_intervals in prediction_dict.items():
    filtered_confidence_intervals = []
    for i in confidence_intervals:
        if i > threshold:
            filtered_confidence_intervals.append(i)
    if len(filtered_confidence_intervals) >= 1:
        filtered_prediction_dict[prediction] = filtered_confidence_intervals
```

I was wondering if I could do the same thing functionally with comprehensions, something like this:

```
filtered_prediction_dict = {prediction: [i for i in confidence_intervals if i > threshold] for prediction, confidence_intervals in prediction_dict.items() if len(filtered_confidence_intervals) >= 1}
```

Of course, python's linter points out that filtered_confidence_intervals hasn't yet been defined in len(filtered_confidence_intervals) in the conditional.

Any way around this?

Comment: `"I was wondering if I could do the same thing functionally with comprehensions"` please don't, not if you want to understand your code 1 week from now

Comment: Just make `filtered_confidence_intervals` a list comprehension, but leave the rest as is.

Comment: Were the answers somehow helpful?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping there was a meta way to avoid computing the list comprehension twice, but it seems unavoidable. 

The any() function is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the two conditions you apply on each of the confidence intervals in a single statement. Also, I recommend putting the filtering for confidence intervals in a list comprehension statement in any case.

The two conditions:

1. confidence interval > threshold (the `if i > threshold`)
2. one or more confidence intervals are are bigger than the threshold (the `len(filtered_confidence_intervals) >= 1`)

Expressed in a single statement:

- `any(ci > threshold for ci in confidence_intervals)`

**The resulting list-comprehension version** (split up for readability):

```py
{
    p: [ci for ci in cis if ci > threshold]  # only keep ci > threshold
    for p, cis in prediction_dict.items()  # iterate through the items
    if any(ci > threshold for ci in cis)  # only consider items with at least one ci > threshold
}
```

*IMHO this is not less readable than `for`-loops, but I guess this is a matter of taste and use.*

---

If you want to keep `for`-looping:

```py
filtered_prediction_dict = {}
for prediction, confidence_intervals in prediction_dict.items():
    if any(ci > threshold for ci in confidence_intervals):
        filtered_prediction_dict[prediction] = [ci for ci in confidence_intervals if ci > threshold]
```

---

*A note to your comment about the python's linter pointing out that `filtered_confidence_intervals` hasn't yet been defined:*

Very often linters are quite accurate and this case is no exception. `filtered_confidence_intervals` is defined per item in `prediction_dict` so there is no way you can iterate through `prediction_dict` and have a test about the length of `filtered_confidence_intervals`.

You would need to replace the statement:

```
len(filtered_confidence_intervals) >= 1
```

in the list comprehension by

```
len([ci for ci in confidence_intervals if ci > threshold]) >= 1
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
filtered_prediction_dict = {prediction: [i for i in confidence_intervals if i > threshold] for prediction, confidence_intervals in prediction_dict.items() if any(e >= threshold for e in  confidence_intervals)}
```

in this way you check that your filtered_prediction_dict doesn't have any empty list

or you can use:

```
filtered_prediction_dict = {prediction: [i for i in confidence_intervals if i > threshold] for prediction, confidence_intervals in prediction_dict.items() if max(confidence_intervals) >= threshold}
```

the second version iterate twice over each element from your lists, the first has some redundant iterations, but even so both solutions may be faster than using for statements